# Why would `reload!` in the Rails console cause "superclass mismatch for class" (Rails 4)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance, autoload, superclass

I am getting the "superclass mismatch for class" error when I run `reload!` in the Rails console. I have some super simple classes defined in ruby, something like this:

```
# base_class.rb
module A
  module B
    module C
      class BaseClass
        def close
          #stub
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And:

```
# more_specific.rb
module A
  module B
    module C
      class MoreSpecific < BaseClass
        def initialize
          # ... 
        end

        def close
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I can see that in fact there's a problem because if I do this before I do `reload!`:

```
A::B::C::MoreSpecific.superclass.equal? A::B::C::BaseClass
```

I get `true`, and then if I do it after I get the error, I get a `false`. Additionally, the `object_id` of the `BaseClass` does in fact change.

Why might this happen? I've checked for additional references to the `MoreSpecific` class in the codebase because I thought that might lead to the BaseClass being established as a constant more than once, but did not see anything.

What could be causing the object_id of `A:B:C::BaseClass` to switch after the `reload!`?

Comment: Note that you're using Rails, not pure Ruby, and that this question is about Rails autoloading behavior within the Rails console.

Answer (score 1):

### Autoloading Modules Without a Require Statement

`reload!` is a Rails console method, not a standard Ruby method. While there could be other causes for the behavior you're seeing, it's worth noting that your C module in *more_specific.rb* doesn't `require base_class` at runtime, and may be losing its lookup; Rails may not [autoload](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) modules the way you're expecting without it.

Make sure that modules that depend on BaseClass contain a `require base_class` statement to be executed when the module reloads. If that doesn't resolve it, there may be other problems with your code as well that aren't shown in your current post.

Comment: A `require` statement would have to target the specific file, no? Could you give an example of what this require might look like?

Comment: Hmm, the `autoload` docs for Rails say in section 9.3: "Files defining constants to be autoloaded should never be required".